# Convert string to number in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following where clause:

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 6, status: "Completed")
=> #<OnlineCourseRegistration id: 142, cart_id: 150, user_id: 7069, course_class_id: 681, created_at: "2017-07-15 22:06:06", updated_at: "2017-07-20 23:59:01", exam_attempts: 1, exam_completed_at: "2017-07-20 23:57:32", evaluation_completed_at: "2017-07-20 23:59:01", status: "Completed", score: "87", add_extension: false, retest_cart_id: nil, retest_purchased_at: nil>
```

I would also like to add that the score would be greater than 70, so something like...

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681, status: "Completed", :score.to_i > 70).last
```

...but of course, this doesn't work. Is there a way to do this within the where clause?

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord where accepts `string` as query constructor

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where("course_class_id = ? AND status = ? AND score > ?", 681, "Completed", 70).last
```

Comment: That worked...thanks! I did have to tweak it a bit. Since score is a string I had to add quotes around the score `OnlineCourseRegistration.where("course_class_id = ? AND status = ? AND score > ?", 681, "Completed", "70")`

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use raw SQL you can use the Arel methods, for example:

```
OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 681, status: "Completed").where(OnlineCourseRegistration.arel_table[:score].gt(70)).last
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity I wanted to add these [cast solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47230405/is-this-the-right-rails-query-when-searching-for-a-score) as an answer also:

```
where("score::int >= ?", 80)         # PostgreSQL-specific casting syntax
where("cast(score as int) >= ?", 80) # Standard SQL type cast
```