# Is this the right Rails query when searching for a score?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following query...

```
CourseRegistration.where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", "80")
```

First, yes, the score field is a string in the DB. This [mostly] works, however, scores of 100 are not being returned. I can query `.where("score >= ?", "080")` and it does return all scores from 80-100 as I want, but it does quite feel right. Is there another way I should be doing this? Or, maybe someone could take a stab at explaining exactly how this query is working so I feel better about it.

Comment: Do you store scores as text? Why not simply `CourseRegistration.where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", 80)`

Comment: what's your score data type?

Comment: Score is a string.

Comment: Can you change the `score` column to an integer? Or is there some reason that it has to be a string?

Comment: You may want to cast the `score` as `integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you should be doing this is to change the `score` column to an integer so that things work as expected. If you can't do that then you could cast the score in the query:

```
where("score::int >= ?", 80)         # PostgreSQL-specific casting syntax
where("cast(score as int) >= ?", 80) # Standard SQL type cast
```

Of course, if the `score` column can contain non-numeric strings then you're going to get exceptions from this sort of query so you may need to account for that. How you account for such data depends on what strange data you have to deal with.

Comment: Yes! I'm using postgres so that first example works perfect.

Comment: How should I handle blank "" values, it throws `(PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

Comment: @StarWars You have empty strings where you're expecting a number wrapped in a string? I would fix your model to convert empty strings to `nil` before they get to the database. Or better, change the column type to `integer` and avoid all the type casting.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to change the score column type to integer. You can do that generating a migration like:

```
rails g migration ChangeScoreType
```

Then you edit your migration file like this:

```
class ChangeScoreType < ActiveRecord::Migration

   change_column :course_registrations, :score, :integer, using: 'company_id::integer'

end
```

also, you can cast score as an INT on your query (should test). Something like this:

```
CourseRegistration.where(status: "Completed").where("CAST(Score AS INT) >= ?", "80")
```

Hope this helps, good luck!